# How to get width and height of uploaded image in PHP

Tags: php

Currently this is my code:

```
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
          echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
          echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " KB<br>";
          echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            echo "images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            $path="images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$image_info = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
$image_width = $image_info[0];
$image_height = $image_info[1];
```

You can refer to: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php for reference!

NOTE: Check the uploaded file to be image before using "getimagesize" otherwise you will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($path);
echo "Width is : " . $width;
echo "Height is : " . $height;
```

Comment: when i use this code :
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize( $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);  echo "Width is : " . $width;  echo "Height is : " . $height;

this error is occur:
Warning: getimagesize(C:\xampp\tmp\php2B3A.tmp) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\testimg\testing.php on line 52
Width is : Height is :

Comment: you should consider adding some reference and explain why it workrs/should work